# Get orignal schema from Parquet files

Tags: database, parquet, pyarrow

When I create a parquet file with an array using `pyarrow`, the schema will have 2 added nodes nested in the array node `item` and `list` (in more recent versions of `pyarrow` `item` is now `element`).

First I'd like to understand why is that. My guess is that it's related to the Dremel encoding used in parquet.

But most important, how do I get the original schema from a parquet file? I've encountered some parquet files with different names for the 2 added nested types, so skipping them by names is problematic.
I need this for integration of parquet in a DB I'm working on.

The following code generates a `parquet` file with an array of struct

```
arr = []
for i in range(3):
    arr.append([{"val": 1, "key": 1}, {"val": 1, "key": 1}])

table = pyarrow.table({
    "my_array": arr
})

file_path = "/data/minio/ne-bucket/repro/data.parquet"
writer = pq.ParquetWriter(file_path, table.schema)
writer.write_table(table)
writer.close()
parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile("/data/minio/ne-bucket/repro/data.parquet")
schema = parquet_file.schema
print(schema)
```

Here's the result, note the added `list` and `element`:

```
required group field_id=-1 schema {
  optional group field_id=-1 my_array (List) {
    repeated group field_id=-1 list {
      optional group field_id=-1 element {
        optional int64 field_id=-1 key;
        optional int64 field_id=-1 val;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, it's not very clear to me what you expect. Is your problem that the list element is called `element` instead of `item`, or that your key/val fields are nested in a list? It would help if you can edit your question and add the parquet schema you would like to have.

Comment: Hi, my question is why does `pyarrow` adds the 2 nodes `item` and `element` and secondly, given a parquet schema, how can I know which node was added and which one was there originally.

Comment: What do you mean by originally? Again it's not clear to me what you are comparing with / expecting in terms of schema. If you don't want the `list` and `element` nodes, and just want a parquet file file made of a `key` and `val` column, you should construct your table this way: `table = pa.Table.from_pylist([{"val": 1, "key": 1}, {"val": 2, "key": 2}])`